# How to run a unit Test in Visual Studio 2010 using Watin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, watin

I have created a class library prject, and created a class as described in the [Video Tutorial at Watin](http://watin.org/documentation/getting-started/)

and using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
[TestFixture]
[RequiresSTA]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
    {
        using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
            browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

            Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
        }
    }

}
}
```

now what is the next step, How to run the test? Do I add the class library to a project and run calls the test method from code? or do I create a Unit Test Project (how?) ?

Thanks

Comment: I answered this in a previous thread...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685263/watinhow-to-use-the-automated-test-run-result-as-i-am-unable-to-get-the-way-of
HTH!

Comment: Thanks, so what you mean is that I need to run the test externally, like from a Console Application? Is this the best approach?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

To execute your test you need to compile your code, then run the test through a test runner.

The first way I ever did this was using the NUnit GUI

1. Compile your code to a class library.  The result being a .dll file; something like `MyTests.dll`
2. Open the NUnit GUI.  Start -> Programs -> etc etc etc.
3. In the NUnit GUI, open the .dll file that contain your tests.
4. In the NUnit GUI, select the test(s) you wish to run and click the *Run* button.

There are plenty of other ways to run your tests, but I believe the NUnit GUI to be the most basic for NUnit tests.  Other options include: In Visual Studio via ReSharper, Gallio, in VS via External Tools, and many others.